# PyArrow Table: Filter rows

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I have a `RecordBatch` from a Plasma DataStore which I can read into either a `pyarrow.RecordBatch` or a `pyarrow.Table`. I am now trying to filter out rows before converting it to pandas (`to_pandas`).

Is there a way of using the `filter` methods from the new Dataset API (that you can use on ParquetDataset) on a `pyarrow.Table`? This would allow me to us a filter like this:

`[[('date', '=', '2020-01-01')]]`

Looking at the source code both `pyarrow.Table` and `pyarrow.RecordBatch` appears to have a filter function but at least `RecordBatch` requires a boolean mask.

Is this possible? The reason is that the dataset contains a lot of strings (and/or categories) which are not zero-copy, so running `to_pandas` actually introduces significant latency and I'm only every looking for about 20% of the dataset.

Regards,
Niklas

Comment: any update for this question...

Comment: @qaiser Yes and no, it's waiting to be enabled by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7945

Answer (score 9):

This is now possible:

```
import pyarrow as pa

my_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [pa.array(['foo', 'bar', 'foo'], pa.string())],
    names=['col1']
)

# Using the high level API with expressions:
filtered_table = my_table.filter(pa.compute.field("col1") == "FOO")

# Using a lower level API:
filtered_table = my_table.filter(pa.compute.equal(my_table['col1'], 'foo'))
```

Comment: Great! That was very helpful. Do you know if it also possible yet to filter on a union of conditions on the same column?

Comment: I'm now doing this btw:     
```
def filter_options(table: pa.Table, filter_values: Iterable, colname: str):
        tables = []
        for filter_val in filter_values:
            tables.append(table.filter(pa.compute.equal(table[colname], filter_val)))
        return pa.concat_tables(tables)
```

But I'm not sure how this will behave w.r.t memory? Will new tables be made, or will views be adjusted?

Comment: The documentation for `pa.compute.filter` doesn't say anything about its behaviour in terms of memory. I suspect it returns a view, given it doesn't receive a memory pool as an argument. PS: if you're worried about performances you should consider using `pa.compute.is_in` in your case, instead of pa.compute.eqal`

Comment: This is most excellent example.  This only shows a "where" clause for a single column, however; is there an easy way to do this on two columns?

Comment: @AubreyRobertson `my_table.filter((pa.compute.field("col1") > 0) & (pa.compute.field("col2") != 1))`

Answer (score 1):

The question above was for the equivalent of

```sql
WHERE date = '2020-01-01'
```

It is worth mentioning the range of PyArrow functions available for giving a wider range of selection conditions on https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/compute.html#containment-tests

```py
# import pyarrow.compute  as pc 
# WHERE test_table.name LIKE 'T%'
filtered_table = test_table.filter(pc.match_like(test_table["name"],"T%"))
```

As a filter returns a table structure you can chain filters one after the other.

```py
# WHERE test_table.name LIKE 'T%' AND test_table.date_updated = '2020-01-01'
filtered_table = test_table.filter(
    pc.match_like(test_table["name"],"T%")
).(
    pc.equal(test_table["date_updated"], "2020-01-01")
)
```

Comment: I can't get this approach to work. I think you need a `.filter` in the chain to avoid a syntax error. When I do get the chain working I end up with an error `pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Filter inputs must all be the same length`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984452/chaining-filters-with-pyarrow

Answer (score 1):

You can filter a table just like you would with a pandas `DataFrame`:

```py
import pyarrow.compute as pc

>>> len(table)
34546

>>> filt = (pc.field('year') == 1983) & (pc.field('month') == 6)
>>> len(table.filter(filt))
372
```