# Chaining filters with pyarrow

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am trying to search a table in pyarrow using multiple parameters.
It looks like filters can be chained, but I am missing the magical incantation to make it actually work.

Table is loaded from CSV, so the structure works — I can filter using a single condition and the results are as expected.

Chaining the filters:

```
table.filter(
   compute.equal(table['a'], a_val)
).filter(
   compute.equal(table['b'], b_val)
).filter(
   compute.equal(table['c'], b_val)
)
```

Results in an error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Filter inputs must all be the same length
```

I suspect the issue is that the second filter is on the original `table` and not the filtered output of the first filter.

Comment: This, maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430288/pyarrow-table-filter-rows

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I was inspired by that, but it only has a single condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine 2 filters together with `and_`:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as compute


table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [
        pa.array([1,2,2], pa.int32()),
        pa.array(["foo","bar","hello"], pa.string())
    ],
    ['a', 'b']
)


compute.filter(
    table,
    compute.and_(
        compute.equal(table['a'], 2),
        compute.equal(table['b'], 'hello'),
    )
)
```

Comment: This approach should be more efficient than making two calls to `filter`.

Comment: I actually have more than two filters. I will make the question clearer. I was playing with and, but nesting it further results in some very ugly code.

Comment: @Pace I did some testing and and is actually slower than making two calls.

Comment: @TobyHede Thanks for the information.  I'll do some benchmarking myself when I get a chance.  If you have the time I'd encourage you to file a JIRA on the Arrow project with a simple reproducible case.

Comment: I think for performance, it depends on the amount of row each filter removes and how many columns there are in the table. It'd be nice if there were a high level API for combining filters (similar to what `pyarrow.parquet.read_table` does).

Answer (score 1):

I believe your suspicion is correct.

The first call to `table.filter` gives an output table that is smaller then the original table, but your expression in the second filter call still depends on the original table, which is now to large.
To fix this, it should be enough to simply save the table back to a variable after the first call.
For instance like this:

```py
table = table.filter(
   compute.equal(table['a'], a_val)
)
table.filter(
   compute.equal(table['b'], b_val)
)
```

Comment: This is basically how I've hacked it together, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way to chain multiple filters is like this. The benefit is that you can have optional filters based on conditions.

```py
filter_a = compute.is_in(df["col1"], pa.array(['a','b']))
filter_b = compute.is_in(df["col2"], pa.array(['a','b']))

masks = [filter_a, filter_b]

if True: # Optional Condition
    masks.append(compute.is_in(df["col3"], pa.array(['a','b']))


mask = [all(x) for x in zip(*masks)]
items = df.filter(mask).to_pylist()
```